# How is $y=\int y' dx$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm currently learning about integrals and I'm struggling to understand what my professor gave here:

$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}\iff dy=y' dx\implies y=\int y'dx$.

Now I get that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is supposed to be a derivative, and $dy$ is an infinitesimal change in $y$, but how does taking the integral of $dy$ give us $y$? I thought the integral of a function is another function, the derivative of which gives us the initial function, but I don't see how taking the derivative of $y$ give us $dy$. Somebody please explain.

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus (part $2$)? It states $y’$ is integrable then $y=\int y’$ (and there are many intuitive explanations for this e.g. the small relative change in the area is “basically equal” to the value of the function times the base - rectangles)

Comment: Unfortunately my professor said nothing about "the fundamental theorem of calculus". We just went head on into integrals right after finishing derivatives. The curriculum is completely broken in the balkans, and we don't even have such a thing as calculus, this is taught under a real analysis class. Anyways, I still don't get how what you said follows from $dy=y'dx$.

Comment: I expect your professor assumed you knew it. If you don’t, I very highly recommend you watch some videos on it e.g. 3blue1brown’s video: they are very visual and usually intuitive

Comment: Not because watching videos is the best way to learn maths, but it is helpful when you’re completely new to a topic

Comment: I think the intended way to interpret this step is "write the symbol $\int$ on the left of both sides of the equality, and then use $\int \mathrm dy = y$" (possibly with some interpretation like "add up all these infinitesimal changes"). This is not the same as "integrate both sides" - this would give you too many $\mathrm d$'s. This isn't really very rigorous at all (and arguably isn't very helpful), but I gather that these sorts of formal manipulations can be quite common as a heuristic/mnemonic in applied maths!

Answer (score 4):

The fact that $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$ is just notation, and the implication $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}\implies y=\int y'\,dx$ is simply by definition of the indefinite integration symbol. So, this 'implication' isn't really anything deep at all; it's just definition. Whenever we write the symbol $\int f(x)\,dx$ what we mean is we're looking for some function $F$ which is differentiable at every point of its domain, and satisfies $F'=f$. So, the step of 'multiplying' $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}\iff dy=y'\,dx$ followed by "integrating" $y=\int dy=\int y'\,dx$ is unnecessary (in fact pointless) and confusing. Now a remark about terminology: 'indefinite integral' is an unfortunate piece of terminology, a better term would be 'anti-derivative', because that's literally what it is (finding a function which when differentiated gives the original function).

On the other hand, a very non-trivial statement is the second fundamental theorem of calculus (mentioned in the comments), which states that if $y:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is a differentiable function with derivative $y':[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ that is Riemann integrable, then
\begin{align}
y(b)-y(a)&=\int_a^by'\equiv \int_a^by'(t)\,dt,
\end{align}
where the $\equiv$ just means "same thing different notation". This is a non-trivial statement because it connects two separate and major ideas of calculus: it combines derivatives (slopes/linear approximation) and integrals (summation and areas under curves) into a single equation. Hence it's called the '**Fundamental** Theorem of Calculus (2)'.